# chrome extension opens with page load

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I need to create a chrome extension that for every web page te he user opens - he will have a button on top of the page (similar to the google translate extension - just that it will appear with page load, without the need to press a button) - preessing on it will do some activity.

from what i saw - the way to do it is to create a content script that will add an iframe that includes the button on the window.onload. just before i do that - i want to be sure there is no more simple way of doing that.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi! I decided to use the iframe because I need a big button - that have text on it, and the icon browser action gives is not big enough.     but when I am trying to add to the image (that I used instead of button) onclick event in the java script file - it doesnot work... from some reason i get null when i am trying to use getElementByID. this is the code:<html>

<body>

<input type= "image"  class=imgA1 src= "logo.png"  id="logo1"> 
</body>
</html>

Comment: @BilltheLizard: this is a different question already asked separately: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25296837/iframe-on-click-chrome-extension

Comment: Whoops! Thanks @Xan. I'll roll back my edit.

Answer (score 1):

There is an experimental [infobar API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/infobars), but it's unknown when, *if ever*, it becomes stable.

As-is, you really need to inject your UI into the page DOM from a content script, with an `iframe` being a good solution to separate your UI from the page.

Answer (score 0):

If it's just a button for each page then you could use a [Browser Action](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction)

If you'd like for it to actually be in the page then an iframe is a good way to go.

Comment: I think OP was referring to this extension: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-translate/aapbdbdomjkkjkaonfhkkikfgjllcleb As you can see, it has an infobar-like UI in the page.

Comment: I see. To be honest I don't really like page actions anyway, it just doesn't seem like an intuitive place to have a button for an extension. It's (slightly) removed from the other extensions and it's removed from the page content. Anyway just figured it can't hurt to suggest in case OP likes the idea since it sounds like they only have 1 button.

Comment: Chrome docs for page actions expressly say that if you want a page action for most (all) pages, you should do a browser action.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense.